# sshfs hangs terminal on brand new Mac M1

Tags: macos, sshfs

Brand new Mac (OS 12.0.1, M1 chipset) sshfs and Fuse installed from https://osxfuse.github.io. I do:

```
sudo sshfs -d mayacc@myhost.com:/home/myacc ~/mnt
```

The terminal hangs, can't ^C the process.

It works fine on my Intel Mac.

Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `sshfs` without `sudo` ?

Comment: From the man page for `sshfs`:  
 "It is recommended to run SSHFS as regular user (not as root)."

Comment: (I can't find any good solution apart from hard restarting either.)  See also: https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues/856, [ssh - How to avoid sshfs freezing? - Super User](https://superuser.com/q/443878) [1](https://serverfault.com/q/1069950), [2](https://superuser.com/q/249611), [3](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/235309), [4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/260090)

Answer (score 0):

The hang is because the user mode component of SSHfs (the one the driver in the kernel calls out) hangs, and because the driver is blocked your process is stuck in an uninterruptible state (wherein it won't respond to signals, which your ^C is (SIGINT)).

It's not necessarily an Intel vs. M1 issue. It *might* be as simple as a connectivity issue between your M1 and (your)host.com. (there's very little info in your question to deduce what the problem is, but I'd suggest check the full stack, from basic ping, through TCP 22, through ssh keys in your ~/.ssh folder)